# How to lower the height of the bars with ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

I would like the height of the left bars made with the ChartJS library to be equivalent to the right ones...

[image: Actual result]

With stackOverflow topics I found this method (decrease the size of the parent container) but the bars overflow (they are not in absolute position).

[image: result with height on container parent]
Code I tried :

```
<div class="content competencesHeight" style="height: 100px !important;">
   <canvas class="skills"
      data-dataset3="{{ baseSkillsAndScores.managerLevels[i]* 20|json_encode }}"
      data-dataset4="{{ baseSkillsAndScores.minimalLevels[i] * 20|json_decode }}"
      data-label1="{{ 'legends.average_manager_evaluation'|trans({}, 'dashboard') }}"
      data-label2="{{ 'legends.average_expected_levels'|trans({}, 'dashboard') }}"
                                >
      </canvas>

 </div>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: on the style part of the content div, what happens if you hard code the width:100px; or what ever exact length you want in pixel quantity.  If you apply that to both segments that generate the bars, they should be identical width I would think.

Comment: style="height: 100px !important;width:100px;"